# how to write a raycast hit script that recognises a specific game object and doesn't use tags

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

So I'm trying to write a script, it should work in a way that I'm able to put a game object in the inspector, have that object be recognised when looked at with a camera, and when looked, it should also enable an animation and image sprite. I want to use this script without tags as it doesn't single out the specific aniamtion I want played, but it's almost impossible to get it working right and there's almost no tutorials on identifying RayCast.hit with GameObject instead of Tag.

Is there a way to do it, or can this only be accomplished with tags?

```
using UnityEngine;

public class selectionManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator outlineAnim;
    public GameObject image;
    public GameObject hitObject;
    public Vector3 collision = Vector3.zero;
    public LayerMask layer;


    private void Update()
    {
        var ray = new Ray(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward);
        RaycastHit hit;
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject.name(hitObject))
        {
            if (hitObject != null)
            {
                outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOff", true);
                outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOn", false);
            }
            outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOn", true);
            image.SetActive(true);
        }
        else if (hitObject != null)
        {
            outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOff", true);
            outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOn", false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can use the name: `if (hit.collider.gameObject.name == "YourObject")` or you define the gameobject in your script and check it like this: `if (hit.collider.gameObject == YourObject)`

Comment: thanks, i was able to make it work, but unity says that ".collider" is depreciated, so i had to convert it to getcomponent <collider>, which adds a whole bunch of errors whenever i look at other objects, is there a way to fix that?

Comment: You can probably still use `.collider` even tho it's deprecated (I assume you are using a new version of Unity). Otherwise you could look up which collider your gameObject uses (BoxCollider, CircleCollider, MeshCollider) and use `GetComponent<MeshCollider>`

Comment: yeah, i tried that but unity is forcing me to use GetComponent, and i still keep getting errors in the console how the script is trying to access a collider from an object but it doesn't have any. Would i have to try some other method or, should it just put colliders on those objects to make it easier on myself.

Comment: Can the hitObject be assigned after the if judgment?if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject != null )
        {
            hitObject = hitInfo.collider.gameObject; 
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you can use no more filters (layers, tags) etc but you solely want to rely on the `GameObject` reference (note that the name is quite unreliable) then I would rather use [`Physics.RaycastAll`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.RaycastAll.html) and do e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

public GameObject hitObject;

private void Update()
{
    var ray = new Ray(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward);

    var hits = Physics.RaycastAll(ray);

    var hittingTheHitObject = hits.Any(hit => hit.transform.gameObject == hitObject);

    outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOff", hittingTheHitObject);
    outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOn", !hittingTheHitObject);

    image.SetActive(hittingTheHitObject);
}
```

where [`hits.Any(hit => hit.transform.gameObject == hitObject)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any) basically equals doing

```
private bool Any(RaycastHit[] hits)
{
    foreach(var hit in hits)
    {
        if(hit.transform.gameObject == hitObject) return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: ah i see, I tried to use this method but it doesnt acknowledge the animation or image sprite when hovered over, it just enables it on play, have I done something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

```
If you change the if condition, for example, like this

 private void Update()
{
    var ray = new Ray(this.transform.position, this.transform.forward);
    RaycastHit hit;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject != null)
    {
        hitObject = hitInfo.collider.gameObject;
        if (hitObject != null)
        {
            outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOff", true);
            outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOn", false);
        }
        outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOn", true);
        image.SetActive(true);
    }
    else if (hitObject != null)
    {
        outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOff", true);
        outlineAnim.SetBool("outlineOn", false);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, what is hitInfo reffering to? is that another gameobject?